# Overwrite laravel 5 helper function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the `response()` helper very often and I just return the data with a message to the user. Now I have to include the http status code as well, but I don't want to change every response (which is likely bad anyway).

So I'm trying to overwrite the `response()` helper function by creating my own `helpers.php` within `app/Http/helpers.php`.

When I add it to my composer files, it does autoload the current helpers.php from the framework first and when I add it before the autload include in `bootstrap/global.php` I wont be able to use the `app()` and other Laravel functions.

How would I be able to solve this issue? I just want to include the status code as well in the response array.

Answer (score 16):

All Laravel helper functions written with this logic

```
if ( ! function_exists('response'))
{
    function response($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = array())
    {
         // function body
    }
}
```

for first Laravel check is this function exists, if it exists, Laravel will not define this function again(otherwise it will throw fatal error).
So if you will define your function before autoloader include  `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php` file, 
you can define your custom response function.

Unfortunately there is no way to say composer load first your `autoload.files` section, then laravel `autoload.files`. But you can do small hack ...

open `bootstrap/autoload.php` file and include your file before autoloader

```
// file with your custom helper functions
require __DIR__.'/../app/app/Http/helpers.php'; 
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: You can use app instance in function, as you will call function later, when app instance exists.

Answer (score 10):

I've just had to do this in order to override the `now()` helper so I can control the apparent time when running tests. I followed the [regular advice](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/override-functions-in-supporthelpersphp) of creating `app/Http/helpers.php` and then adding it to `bootstrap/autoload.php` like so:

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/helpers.php'; // added
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

This usually works because as Marty says, all helpers are only defined if there's not an existing function with that name. So the two lines above load your custom helpers, then perform all vendor autoloading, which includes Laravel's helpers, and your already-defined function takes precedence.

But unfortunately, `autoload.php` doesn't seem to be used when testing with Behat, which is what I'm using. So I needed an alternative solution. Long story short, the only easy way to ensure that files get autoloaded before vendor files is by using the https://github.com/funkjedi/composer-include-files package. To quote from its readme:

> In the past simply modifying `bootstrap/autoload.php` to include helpers was sufficient. However new versions of PHPUnit include the Composer Autoloader prior to executing the PHPUnit bootstrap file. Consequently this method of overriding helpers is no longer viable as it will trigger a fatal error when your bootstrap file is included.

So I installed this package using `composer require funkjedi/composer-include-files` and then added this to `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "include_files": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Once that's done, run `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate the autoload files. Now the overrides work both during regular app operation, and when running tests!

Comment: This is the only possible way I was able to force the `url()` helper in Lumen to generate https URLs.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not going to directly answer your question since I don't know if there's a solution (without changing Laravels `helpers.php` or renaming your function)

However there is a solution from the framework for this common use case. [Response Macros](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses)

You can define a macro (this is done in a service provider)

```
Response::macro('foo', function($value){
    // do some stuff
    return Response::make($value);
});
```

And you can use it like this:

```
return response()->foo('bar');
```

Comment: If you need more help writing the actual macro I'd need to know what exactly it is supposed to do...

Comment: Well I know it can be done like this, but I would like to know if anybody has a solution instead of just changing every method or creating another one. Laravel should be flexibel for those kind of stuff..

Comment: Either way this is a nice solution to the problem. Helpers like this are an irrelevance to most people using Laravel. The response facade and the specific response classes are much better than the helper.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.5+ laravel doesn't have `bootstrap/autoload.php`
and  you must use a package like https://github.com/funkjedi/composer-include-files

**how to do it:**

first run command

`composer require funkjedi/composer-include-files`

then add your helper functions file path in composer.json

```
{
    "extra": {
        "include_files": [
            "/path/to/file/you/want/to/include",
            "/path/to/another/file/you/want/to/include"
        ]
    },
}
```

then just do

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: See the related laravel ideas issue: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1569