# Override Laravel Vendor Method in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to add multilanguage functionality to existing laravel project. Currently I have the following route:

```
$user_route = function() {
  ....
};

Route::group([
  'prefix'     => ''
], $user_route 
);

Route::group([
  'prefix'     => '{language}', 
  'middleware' => 'set.lang'
], $user_route 
);
```

Each anchor uses `route()` helper from Laravel. Since I have route with 'language' prefix, I need to pass `$language` from every `route()`. There are lot of `route()` and I don't think updating every route to `route('name', ['language' => \App::getLocale()])` is a good option. The project already have Helper class and I plan to override `route()` method from `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator` with my custom method. This is what I have tried :

Functions.php

```
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator as Url;
....

function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
  $parameters = array_add($parameters, 'language', \App::getLocale());

  $url = new Url();

  return $url->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```

Which obviously return error :

```
FatalErrorException in Functions.php line 158:

Cannot redeclare route() (previously declared in
C:\...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:693)
```

I read about [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container) but as far as my understanding, only used to manage class dependencies and performing dependency injection. How to handle this correctly? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: IMHO its easier to override the helper function route(). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474640/overwrite-laravel-5-helper-function

Comment: You also look at adding a middleware to the route group that would inject $language into the request object.

Comment: @dparoli Thank you, I'll check the link

Comment: @jim0thy Already tried, but it give the following error :
`Missing required parameters for [Route: art] [URI: {language}/art-prints]`
Am I missed something?