# Override helpers in Laravel 5 with PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, composer-php

I have been following the advices provided here to override my `route`, creating my very own `helpers.php` and loading it in the bootstrap. It works fine in the browser but not so much in PHPUnit:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare route() (previously declared in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:707) in /var/www/app/Http/helpers.php on line 25
```

It seems that PHPUnit is calling the vendor autoload instead of the bootstrap set in `phpunit.xml` and I don't know how to override that.

This is the call stack I get when throwing an Exception inside Laravel's `helpers.php`

```
#0 /var/www/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
#1 /var/www/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequirefaa86f5c74caea0c3ebf4fa6247e01ed('f0906e6318348a7...', '/var/www/vendor...')
#2 /var/www/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitfaa86f5c74caea0c3ebf4fa6247e01ed::getLoader()
#3 /var/www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(51): require('/var/www/vendor...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 699
```

Only elements I have not control on.

## EDIT

I have made some edits in my `composer.json`, to load my helpers. It now generates `vendor/composer/autoload_files.php`:

```
<?php

// autoload_files.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    // ...

    'f0906e6318348a765ffb6eb24e0d0938' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php',
    '58571171fd5812e6e447dce228f52f4d' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php',
    '224ac75459a4044275cfdffe33336135' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/helpers.php',
);
```

Basically, this could fix my problem if I had a way to inject my helpers before Laravel's.

I really love debugging this thing and hear this little song in my head "What a nice idea to have those neat static helpers", it's grooooovy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite laravel 5 helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474640/overwrite-laravel-5-helper-function)

Comment: @ceejayoz I am already following whatever is displayed here.

Comment: Take a look at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/unit-testing-and-helper-functions-problem and see if the comments help you track it down.

Comment: Thanks for that! Nothing ground breaking but similar problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the **edit** of the question you will understand that injecting the file in the autoload does not work.

https://packagist.org/packages/funkjedi/composer-include-files is here to solve this.

First run:

```
composer require funkjedi/composer-include-files
```

Then update your `composer.json` `extra` field:

```
"extra": {
    "include_files": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ]
}
```