# Laravel Extend class from Package

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the latest version of the package.

I have extended the package to display error messages like following `App\GlobalIt\Html.php`

```
namespace App\Acme\Html;

use Spatie\Html\Html as SpatieHtml;

class Html extends SpatieHtml
{

    public function text($name = null, $value = null)
    {
        $errorMessage = "Test";

        if ($errorMessage) {
            return $this->input('text', $name, $value)->class('is-invalid')->addChild(html()->div($errorMessage)->class('invalid-feedback'));
       }

       return $this->input('text', $name, $value);
   }
```

Following is the service provider `HtmlServiceProvider.php`

```
namespace App\Acme\Html;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Spatie\Html\Html as SpatieHtml;

class HtmlServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(SpatieHtml::class, Html::class);
    }
}
```

When I use this with `modelForm` the `model` value is always null.

```
{{ html()->form('POST', route('frontend.register.step2'))->open() }}

{{ html()->text('colour') }}
```

This works fine and displays error class if any on submit.

The following does not populate model values

```
{{ html()->modelForm($userDetail,'PATCH', route('frontend.register.edit.details',$userDetail))->open() }}

{{ html()->text('colour') }}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I think the problem here is with the `Spatie/Html` package registers the function 'html' which I do not know how to override.

```
use Spatie\Html\Html;

if (! function_exists('html')) {
    /**
     * @return \Spatie\Html\Html
     */
    function html()
    {
        return app(Html::class);
    }
}
```

How can I override or redeclare this function to point to my `html` class?

Thank you

Comment: Did you register `HtmlServiceProvider` in **config/app.php** ?

Comment: @cbaconier Yes, I did.

Comment: I saw your edit: You can make your own `html()` **helper**  since Spatie uses `if(function_exists('html'))` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019988/8068675

Comment: Or maybe try `$this->app->alias('Spatie\Html\Html', 'App\Acme\Html');` instead of bind. Not sure though

Comment: @cbaconnier I can create the function but aren't packages loaded first? So I can not then redeclare the same function in helpers file.

Comment: @cbaconnier `$thhi->app->alias` did not work either. It does not even go into my overridden class.

Comment: @If you read the SO link, yes you can override package helpers. It's explained by using the package `funkjedi/composer-include-files` since the changes from L5.5. You can also make your own helper like `body()` and use your Html instance

Comment: @cbaconnier I just tried `$this->app->singleton('Spatie\Html\Html', 'App\Acme\Html')` and it seems to work fine. Doing more testing but would like to know the reason why it's working with `singleton`.

Comment: About `alias` the parameters may inverted. Since it's declared as `public function alias($abstract, $alias)` and `'Spatie\Html\Html'` is actually the alias